# How to grant only few previleges ( to execute only DML and DDL statements) to the new user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

How to grant only few previleges ( to execute only DML and DDL statements)  to the new user in MySQL ?

I tried the below command :

```
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON database.* to 'karthik' identified by 'shimoga';
```

But, it is showing Syntax error.

Comment: I tried the below command :

GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON database.* to 'karthik' identified by 'shimoga';

But, it is showing Syntax error.

Comment: Is `database` the actual name of database?

Comment: Actually, it is the very next statement of  the command (after creating the user)                                                                                                             create user 'karthik' identified by 'shimoga';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take out identified by 'shimoga' from your statement.

CREATE USER:

```
CREATE USER 'karthik'@'instance' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';
```

THEN GRANT Privileges:

```
GRANT SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, EXECUTE, INSERT, DROP, ALTER, CREATE ON databaseName.* TO 'karthik'@'instancename';
```

---

Better Solution will be to create a Role. And assign the role to user.
This will make your job easier if you have many users that needs similar privileges.

First Create a Role:

```
CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS 'Developer'@'localhost';
```

Then Assign the required Privileges to the Role.

```
GRANT SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, EXECUTE, INSERT, DROP, ALTER ON databaseName.* TO 'Developer'@'instanceName';
```

Finally Assign the Role to User which you would have already created:

```
GRANT 'Developer'@'localhost' TO 'karthik'@'instanceName'; 

SET DEFAULT ROLE ALL TO 'karthik'@'instanceName';
```